# Hiding multiple tag with same name or class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have using prototype 1.5. Can you please tell me, how can i hide/show the div tag with same name or class.

```
Element.hide('indicate')
```

But, the above line only satisfy to hide the first element only. "indicate" is the id.

Comment: Yes, i know. Ok tell me, how to hide the tag with same name or class.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, the `$$` function is required. It returns an array so you need to [invoke](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/) hide on all items.

```
$$('.indicate').invoke('hide');
```

Or, for bonus showing off points, you can use the function directly as an object:

```
var hideFunc = Element.hide;
$$('.indicate').each(hideFunc);
```

The advantage of this technique means you can easily swap the function for another, such as [a Scriptaculous effect](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/combination-effects/).

```
hideFunc = Effect.SwitchOff;
```

Answer (score 2):

Having the same id for two elements isn't supported in HTML, so there's no methods in Javascript to handle it. No matter what framework you're using.

Comment: hi @LHMathies, i have modified the question. Please tell the solution for that.

Comment: Thanks. But I see that lots of people already gave valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype provides the `$$()` function which you can use to query any CSS selector.

So if you have multiple items with a single class, you can query them like this:

```
$$('.indicate');
```

See the Prototype manual: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

By the way, since you're using Prototype 1.5, I could also mention that it gives you a `.getElementsByClassName()` function as well. However, this has now been deprecated in more recent versions since its functionality is already covered by `$$()`, and to avoid confusion, since modern browsers implement a native function with the same name, but different syntax.

So don't use it, but for the sake of completeness, here is the manual link: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getElementsByClassName

Comment: it's not working. I tried "$$('.indicate').hide();", noting happened. When try to like, $$('.indicate').each {
      function (obj) {
        obj.hide();
      }
    }
it shows error.

Comment: @Mr. Black - I've dropped the part of my answer on how to use `hide`, as I was getting my Prototype and JQuery mixed up. I've left the manual page link in there though, because it's a useful link. Looking at the other answers, I'd say @clockworkgeek's answer looks like it ought to be good.

Answer (score 0):

ID's have to be unique. Select with a class instead.

```
$$('div.indicate').hide();
```

or with its name attribute

```
$$('div[name=indicate]').hide();
```

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. Functional programming FTW!